# Root shell but not Root permission

Tags: android, shell, root, tablet, rooted-device

I have a Tablet approx APPTB104B

```
Reference: http://approx.es/APPTB104B#.UzART85mzRM
```

When I use adb shell I access as root, so technically the device comes rooted by default. I use ADB Konnect

```
Link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rockolabs.adbkonnect
```

which requires root access and it works well, however some applications detect that the device isn't rooted.
This is what shows a Root Checker App

```
Root Checker Screenshot http://imgur.com/ZPfz2qi
```

Here is the Build Info, the board don't fit in the screenshot, but it's value is 'wing'

```
Build Info http://imgur.com/FkpkWlj
```

Any ideas?

**Update**
I will write here the answer, just in case someone didn't see the comments. As @ChrisStratton said, **having root access and letting the apps do things as root are 2 different things**

Comment: An app can only l as launch helpers as root if you have installed some sort of hacked `su` or similar for it to use as a shim.  In contrast adb running as root is more of a development/administration tool and really comes about by a different mechanism.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisStratton for the fast reply. So this means that I have root acces only for development purposes but not "real" root access? That's a shame, I should root my device then...

Comment: Your device is rooted.  If you want to let apps do things as root, you'll have to install one of the various toolkits for that.  But finding existing software is off topic here.